# Create new columns for each Q'uestion in XML file using R

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/QenJ7EnE) an excerpt of the XML file. I figured out how to make a column of all the questions, all the correct answers, and all the incorrect answers. This is the code I used:

```
#loads package
library(XML)
xmlfile=xmlTreeParse("cowen.xml")
class(xmlfile)
xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile) #gives content of root

#Gets all the Questions 
Questions = sapply(getNodeSet(xmltop,"//quiz/question/name/text"), function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
#dataframe of questions
Q = as.data.frame(Questions)

#Gets All the corrects answers
CorrectAnswers = sapply(getNodeSet(xmltop ,"//quiz/question/answer[@fraction='100']/text"), function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
#dataframe of correct answers
CA = as.data.frame(CorrectAnswers)

#Gets all the wrong answers (But it doesnt get it by each question)
WrongAnswers = sapply(getNodeSet(xmltop,"//quiz/question/answer[@fraction='0']/text"), function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
#dataframe of wrong answers
WA = as.data.frame(WrongAnswers)
```

I want to create a data-set with four columns. Column 1 has the question, column 2 has the correct answer, and column 3-5 has the incorrect answers. I'm not sure how to create a loop/function that goes through each node and only gets the wrong answer and then create three columns with each of the wrong answer. In the XML file:
      `<answer fraction="100">` represents a correct answer and 
      `<answer fraction="0">` represents a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just apply functions to the same `getNodeSet`.

```
doc <- xmlParse("file.xml")
q1 <- getNodeSet(doc, "//question[@type='multichoice']")

Q <- sapply(q1, function(x) xpathSApply(x, "./name/text", xmlValue))
CA <- sapply(q1, function(x) xpathSApply(x, "./answer[@fraction='100']/text", xmlValue))
WA <- sapply(q1, function(x) xpathSApply(x, "./answer[@fraction='0']/text", xmlValue))

data.frame(Q, CA, t(WA))
```